# Setting source for MediaElement in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to set the source of a media element in C#. This is what I'm doing

**XAML Part**

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Sound" AutoPlay="False" />

<Button Content="Shout!" Height="123" Name="button2" Width="123" Click="shout_Click" />
```

**C# Part**

```
private void shout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Sound.Source = new Uri("Sounds/fusrodah.wma", UriKind.Relative);
            this.Sound.Play();
        }
```

The above doesn't work. However, If i set the path manually in the xaml it works. How can I set the a `MediaElement`'s source in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you get an error, or does it just not play? Try adding a forward slash, Dovahkiin:

```
this.Sound.Source = new Uri("/Sounds/fusrodah.wma", UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: I tried that, It just doesn't play. Throws no errors, nothing.

PS: I'm guessing you already know the type of app I'm making ;)

Comment: Attach a MediaFailed event to the mediaplayer. `Sound.MediaFailed += new EventHandler<ExceptionRoutedEventArgs>(Sound_MediaFailed);` Check if this event is called and message it contains.

Comment: I did so. Its not failing. Its just not playing it. However i just discovered that if I put a break point just before the play() function and wait for 3 seconds, it plays. Perhaps its speeding through that code? Is there a way for me to make the code 'sleep'?

Comment: You could use `Thread.Sleep` but I wouldn't recommend it as it's not accurate or UI friendly. Instead, try handling the `MediaOpened` event, like you did with the `MediaFailed` event, then put your `Sound.Play()` in that event. It should fire once the media is loaded.

Comment: MediaOpened worked like a charm. Many thanks you've been so helpful on both my questions.