# Change MediaElement Source for Windows Phone Application in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Music.Stop();
        var NewSource = new MediaElement { Source = new Uri("/Assets/Audio/Background/cherished.wav") };
        Music.Source = NewSource.Source;
        Music.Play();
    }
```

I'm making an XAML application that will require me to dynamically change Source of a MediaElement type through C#. I've tried looking around for something and this will was the best answer I could find, however it throws me an exception with the newSource variable being NULL.

Edit:

Replacing the two middle lines with a single line that sets the Music.Source directly and adding UriKind.Relative did the job of changing the Source.

```
Music.Stop();
Music.Source = new Uri("/Assets/Audio/Background/cherished.wav", UriKind.Relative);
Music.Play();
```

However, very next line, which is Music.Play() does not play the file for some reason. If I again press Button1 (Click Event handler just contains Music.Play(); ) it will start playing the file with a little bit of stutter at the beginning.
Let's say if the audio file is 12345 it will play 1-12345.

Comment: Is that something wrong with, setting the `source` for the `MediaElement`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627280/setting-source-for-mediaelement-in-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

- Register MediaOpened event for the MediaElement and put `mediaElement.Play()` in the same event.
- For changing source of MediaElemnt put following code :

  if (mediaElement.Source != null) 
  { 
     mediaElement.Pause(); 
     mediaElement.Source = new Uri("YOUR SOURCE URI",UriKind.Absolute);

  }
- It is working for me.

Comment: I apologize for the incredibly late delay. This project was put on hold and I wasn't active. But yes, this did the trick!